# Узнать value элемента

Tags: jquery, javascript

Добрый вечер. Подскажите новичку.

Есть код:

```
<form class="variants">
    <div class="aks_1">
        <input class="variant" value="1" type="hidden"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Нажать"/>
    </div>
    <div class="aks_2">
        <input class="variant" value="2" type="hidden"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Нажать"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

js

```
$('form.variants').live('submit', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var parent = $(this).parent();
alert(parent.find('input[class=variant]').val()); //так всегда первый
});
```

Собственно, не пойму, как узнать value в блоке `<div class="aks">`. 
Если нажат submit первый, то значение `value=1`.
Если нажат submit второй, то значение `value=2`.

Comment: name предназначен для того, чтобы обработчик формы мог идентифицировать элемент, поэтому плохая идея назвать два input в одной форме одинаковым name

Comment: Теперь сделал разные, все равно выводит первый:

    <form class="variants">
        <div class="aks_1">
            <input class="variant" value="1" type="hidden"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Нажать"/>
        </div>
        <div class="aks_2">
            <input class="variant" value="2" type="hidden"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Нажать"/>
        </div>
    </form>

Comment: @Виктор Ребриков, написал ниже ответ, name не является проблемой неправльной работы вашего скрипта, но на будущее при отправке формы name всё равно лучше делать разные

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю, проблема в самом запросе, вы ведь вешаете событие на `submit` формы, а не на клик по элементу, и вообще событие [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) удалено из jquery 1.7+, поэтому не рекомендую его использовать, посмотрите [этот пример](http://jsfiddle.net/8cvumc5a/1/):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[type='submit']").on('click', function(event) {
       event.preventDefault();
       var parent = $(this).parent();
       alert(parent.find('.item').val());
    });
});
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте подняться до родителя, а уже в нем искать.

```
$('form.variants').live('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var parent = $(this).parent();
    alert(parent.find('input[name=variant]').val());
});
```

Comment: тоже самое при нажатии любой кнопки value=1 выводит

Comment: @Виктор Ребриков, сделайте тоже самое, что предлагает @dimka3210, только добавьте и используйте в скрипте вместо name одинаковый класс у элементов

Comment: Не помогло, все равно при нажатии на любую кнопку value=1.